# How to create a custom navigation bar in Swift Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am working on a chat app for my graduation project in iOS. I designed the following navigation bar:

[image]

Now I am trying to develop above graphic in my Xcode project, but I don't know if this is the correct way to achieve this and doesn't get it like the graphic.

I am using a xib file, that I load in my `ViewController.swift` using an instance of it. Than add it as the `titleView` of the `navigationItem`:

```
let helperView = HelperView()
navigationItem.titleView = helperView
```

This is the result of above code snippet:

[image]

The problem of this result is that it is overlapping the left bar button item and another problem, that I still doesn't figured out is, if the message bubble can have a dynamic height, when it have multiple lines (max is 3 lines).

[image]

Does anyone have experience with this kind of design within Xcode and is this the correct way to do this, or is there a better way to achieve this. Maybe a custom UINavigationController class?

Answer (score 5):

Try create the whole navigation view that you desire, that mean the width is equal to the view, then try use this code to add it

```
    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear

    navigationController?.view.insertSubview(subview, belowSubview: navigationController?.navigationBar)
```

It will makes your navigation bar become invisible but still showing the bar button

**Update**, by dimpiax

But better to override your UINavigationController class, and setup view in `viewDidLoad`

```
navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationBar.backgroundColor = .clear
```

And on dependent viewController's view  – show specific view.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly. I should create the avatar and message bubble correctly in my Xib file, than add above code in the `viewDidAppear` function? What should subview be?

Comment: The subview is the view you want to add, in this case its your `helperView`. You can add the above code in `viewDidLoad`, but keep the pointer variable to your `helperView` to resize the frame in `viewDidLayoutSubview`

Comment: Okay, and what do you mean with the last part about the pointer variable? Do you mean that it's frame should be resizable to it's content?

Comment: What i meant is that if you add this code in `viewDidAppear` it might have a flickering appear, add in `viewDidLoad` then it might have wrong frame, thats why you might want to declare the `headerView` in your view controller scope to change its frame in `viewDidLayoutSubview `

Comment: So the best way to add above code is in de viewdidLayoutSubview function? Sorry if I understand it wrong.

Comment: Add it in `viewDidLoad`, but change the frame of headerView in `viewDidLayoutSubview `

Answer (score 0):

```
// --------------------------------------------------------
// MARK:- Navigation SetUp
// --------------------------------------------------------

private func _navigationBarSetUp(){
    
    ///# Navigatoin bar and title #///
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    navigationItem.title = vEditScreenName
    navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : ColorTheme.white, NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(descriptor: UIFontDescriptor(name: "Poppins-Regular", size: 20), size: 20)]
    self.view.backgroundColor = ColorTheme.vidBoomBrandPurple
    
    ///# Navigation bar back button #///
    
    let btnBack = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
    btnBack.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_back_arrow"), for: .normal)
    btnBack.addTarget(self, action: #selector(_handlebtnBackTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnBack)
    
    ///# Navigation bar explore button #///
    
    let btnExport = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 25))
    btnExport.setTitle("Export", for: .normal)
    btnExport.backgroundColor = .orange
    btnExport.layer.cornerRadius = 18
    btnExport.addTarget(self, action: #selector(_handleBtnExportTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: btnExport)
}


// --------------------------------------------------------
// MARK:- UIBarButtonItem Action
// --------------------------------------------------------

@objc fileprivate func _handlebtnBackTapped() {
    self.player.stop()
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
}

@objc func _handleBtnExportTapped(){
    self.player.stop()
    let svc = ShareVideoVC(nibName: "ShareVideoVC", bundle: nil)
    svc.videoString = videoString
    saveFile()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(svc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: Can you add some details on how to use this code? Where should those methods be placed, do we need to manually call them from a certain location/place?

Comment: Add this code into ViewController class but out of viewdidload and call the function in viewdidload.